# Android SDK - Make a "class" for same attributes of different View elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I defined in my Layout XML a headline and a basic `TextView`. I use these elements very often throughout my app. Until now I just copied and pasted every `TextView` but I guess there must be a way to make a 'class' like in `CSS` where I can define the cut-set of the attributes which are the same for i.e. the headline element.

Any ideas how I can store them into a class or something?

Comment: The class you want is the AttributeSet. Every View has it in it's two of three default constructors.

Comment: or include. that can work as well

Comment: Include could work too I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

TextView implementation

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```